# Celery + SQS is receiving same task twice, with same task id at same time

Tags: flask, celery, amazon-sqs, celery-task

using celery with SQS in flask app
but **celery is receiving same task twice with same task id at same time**, 
running worker like this,
`celery worker -A app.jobs.run -l info --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/celery.log --time-limit=7200 --concurrency=8`
here are the logs of celery

```
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,464: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.jobs.booking.bookFlightTask[657985d5-c3a3-438d-a524-dbb129529443]  
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,465: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.jobs.booking.bookFlightTask[657985d5-c3a3-438d-a524-dbb129529443]  
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,471: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] in booking funtion1
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,473: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] in booking funtion1
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,537: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] book_request_pp
[2019-11-29 08:07:35,543: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] book_request_pp
```

same task received twice and both are running simultaneously,

using celery==4.4.0rc4 , boto3==1.9.232, kombu==4.6.6 with SQS in python flask.
In SQS, Default Visibility Timeout is 30 minutes, and my task is not having ETA and not ack

my task.py

```
from app import app as flask_app
from app.jobs.run import capp
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)

class BookingTasks:
    def addBookingToTask(self):
        request_data = request.json
        print ('in addBookingToTask',request_data['request_id'])
        print (request_data)
        bookFlightTask.delay(request_data)
        return 'addBookingToTask added'

@capp.task(max_retries=0)
def bookFlightTask(request_data):
    task_id = capp.current_task.request.id
    try:
        print ('in booking funtion1')
        ----
```

my config file, config.py

```
import os
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

aws_access_key = quote_plus(os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'))
aws_secret_key = quote_plus(os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY'))

broker_url = "sqs://{aws_access_key}:{aws_secret_key}@".format(
    aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key,
)
imports = ('app.jobs.run',)


## Using the database to store task state and results.
result_backend = 'db' + '+' + os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

and lastly my celery app file, run.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask
from app import app as flask_app
import sqlalchemy
capp = Celery()

capp.config_from_object('app.jobs.config')

# Optional configuration, see the capplication user guide.
capp.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)
 
# SQS_QUEUE_NAME is like 'celery_test.fifo' , .fifo is required
capp.conf.task_default_queue = os.getenv('FLIGHT_BOOKINNG_SQS_QUEUE_NAME')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    capp.start()
```

Comment: What time zone?

Comment: I have not define timezone explicitly anywhere. by default on celery it is UTC.

Comment: any help, insight would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The default SQS visiblity_timeout is 30s. You need to update the celery config value:
`broker_transport_options={'visibility_timeout': 3600}`.

When celery goes to create the queue it will set the visibility timeout to 1h.

NOTE: If you specify the task_default_queue, and the queue has already been created without specifying `broker_transport_options={'visibility_timeout': 3600}`, celery will not update the visibility timeout when restarted with `broker_transport_options={'visibility_timeout': 3600}`. You will need to delete the queue and have celery recreate it.

Comment: Can you explain how you understood that the default `visibility_timeout` (30 seconds) was not enough and should be increased?