# Getting Celery tasks repeated multiple times in production

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm new to Celery, and I created a simple app that connects to a web socket server to receive tasks and schedule them using Celery. My Celery queue display tasks based on the type of the message (text messages first, and then buttons that run the next task if one of them is clicked).
Locally, everything run as expected. But, some tasks are repeated multiple times in production, especially the triggers (buttons). In my production environment, I created a web service for Django and one Celery background worker with a Redis database.

Here are the commands I used to run Celery worker and beat in production:

```bash
# Start command (celery worker and beat)
celery -A bot.celery worker --beat --scheduler django --loglevel=info --concurrency 4
# Start command (Django)
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 bot.asgi:application
```

My Django and Celery settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0" # localhost replaced with the internal Redis URL in production
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379/1" # localhost replaced with the internal Redis URL in production

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'bot.asgi.application'
```

Some of the worker output:

```
Nov 1 09:00:15 AM  [2022-11-01 08:00:15,178: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from celery@srv-cdcl4202i3msb94icl70-5469f7b9d8-gzks7
Nov 1 09:05:33 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:33,207: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[574703ea-51d8-4acf-b9e9-202c37d0cbe5] received
Nov 1 09:05:33 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:33,211: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[ef2b2dd0-f297-4480-9577-da83a44bc244] received
Nov 1 09:05:33 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:33,223: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[a3619feb-9768-4e6b-b8be-966c335eae5f] received
Nov 1 09:05:34 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:34,182: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task schedule_chat_message[a3619feb-9768-4e6b-b8be-966c335eae5f] succeeded in 0.9560789109673351s: None
Nov 1 09:05:34 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:34,272: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task schedule_chat_message[574703ea-51d8-4acf-b9e9-202c37d0cbe5] succeeded in 1.0607709939940833s: None
Nov 1 09:05:34 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:34,280: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task schedule_chat_message[ef2b2dd0-f297-4480-9577-da83a44bc244] succeeded in 1.0533532970002852s: None
Nov 1 09:05:34 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:34,936: INFO/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
Nov 1 09:05:35 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:35,274: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduled to send to chat_1ea56ac at 2022-11-01 08:05:33.211860+00:00 (send_out_chat_message)
Nov 1 09:05:35 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:35,289: INFO/MainProcess] Task send_out_chat_message[37854a6c-d20a-45b1-99ba-37b22d818af4] received
Nov 1 09:05:35 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:35,562: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task send_out_chat_message[37854a6c-d20a-45b1-99ba-37b22d818af4] succeeded in 0.27148923301137984s: None
Nov 1 09:05:38 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:38,090: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduled to send to chat_1ea56ac at 2022-11-01 08:05:33.227478+00:00 (send_out_chat_message)
Nov 1 09:05:38 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:38,096: INFO/MainProcess] Task send_out_chat_message[80ca730b-0ff4-43df-b3ec-2758b0b493df] received
Nov 1 09:05:38 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:38,276: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task send_out_chat_message[80ca730b-0ff4-43df-b3ec-2758b0b493df] succeeded in 0.1784440579940565s: None
Nov 1 09:05:44 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:44,359: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduled to send to chat_1ea56ac at 2022-11-01 08:05:33.226634+00:00 (send_out_chat_message)
Nov 1 09:05:44 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:44,365: INFO/MainProcess] Task send_out_chat_message[a1bcff89-78af-41b6-8e81-95aa5d3172d3] received
Nov 1 09:05:44 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:44,561: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task send_out_chat_message[a1bcff89-78af-41b6-8e81-95aa5d3172d3] succeeded in 0.19544574100291356s: None
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,089: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[a83a6683-1750-422f-8494-7226152249b4] received
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,099: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[d983a9d0-2243-4a87-9844-5f2e986f7626] received
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,103: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[f30d05ec-257f-4516-bfcb-5880b85d3e85] received
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,109: INFO/MainProcess] Task schedule_chat_message[f8e1a7a3-21a9-41f3-a8d9-9ceae4f0c10f] received
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,864: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task schedule_chat_message[a83a6683-1750-422f-8494-7226152249b4] succeeded in 0.773912389006s: None
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,869: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task schedule_chat_message[d983a9d0-2243-4a87-9844-5f2e986f7626] succeeded in 0.7689848589943722s: None
Nov 1 09:05:50 AM  [2022-11-01 08:05:50,968: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task schedule_chat_message[f30d05ec-257f-4516-bfcb-5880b85d3e85] succeeded in 0.8630019359989092s: None
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: This started happening with my setup after > 5 yrs with absolutely no issues. Tearing my hairs…

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Redis as broker, it seems to be related to this celery [issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5935). It looks like developers using SQS may encounter a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123536/celery-sqs-is-receiving-same-task-twice-with-same-task-id-at-same-time).

Answer (score 1):

While the topic is quite old I would like to make some additions to txicos' answer for those still having the same problem, or people like me who met with this error from out of nowhere in years old systems.

First of all if you checked your current celery beat process with `ps -Af | grep celerybeat` you would probably see that there are actually more than one celery beat process at work. So tasks being multiplied is only normal, there are multiple beats and workers at play afterall.

In the github source provided by txicos its argued this error might be related to timezone issues (UTC being false) or it could be solved with usage of visibility_timeout variable ([celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html#visibility-timeout) for it). Sadly this didn't work for me, only other option is to change brokers it seems.

You can follow through [rabbitmq celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/rabbitmq.html#setting-up-rabbitmq) for installations, which is quite straight forward and removed the error for me. While I would rather fix the error that occurs with redis servers but this is an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, we managed to solve the problem...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiw7J.png)

the problem was that we schedule the task in django (m/h/dm/my/d) * 13 * * 1-5.

We made this to run the task at 13pm every day of week, but in django we need to specify minutes!

after editing the schedule to (m/h/dm/my/d) 00 13 * * 1-5, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Need to increase the Visibility timeout, here is how you can do it.

[https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/4.4.2/getting-started/brokers/redis.html][1]

**Visibility timeout**
If a task isn’t acknowledged within the Visibility Timeout the task will be redelivered to another worker and executed.

This causes problems with ETA/countdown/retry tasks where the time to execute exceeds the visibility timeout; in fact, if that happens it will be executed again, and again in a loop.

So you have to increase the visibility timeout to match the time of the longest ETA you’re planning to use.

Note that Celery will redeliver messages at worker shutdown, so having a long visibility timeout will only delay the redelivery of ‘lost’ tasks in the event of a power failure or forcefully terminated workers.

Periodic tasks won’t be affected by the visibility timeout, as this is a concept separate from ETA/countdown.

You can increase this timeout by configuring a transport option with the same name:

```
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 43200}
```

The value must be an int describing the number of seconds.